# Does Internet Explorer 11 Enterprise Mode supports IE9, IE10 besides IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer

When I set "IE9 DocumentMode" in Enterprise Mode Site List Manager, restart IE11 the console still shows that it's working in Internet Explorer 8.

I want to know if EMIE supports IE9 and IE10. See below in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/11/announcing-improvements-to-the-enterprise-mode-site-list.aspx#10573728):

> Sites can be added to the Enterprise Mode Site List to fix
>   compatibility problems with sites originally written for IE8, IE9, or
>   IE10.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, IE11 in EM is an emulated IE8 which is why it still shows as IE8. This is also evident in the user-agent string if you try to sniff it. The rationale behind why EM chose IE8 as the engine can be found in this blog post:

> Internet Explorer 8 still has more than 20% of the desktop browser
>   market share; despite the fact that IE9, IE10, and IE11 have
>   superseded IE8, many customers still rely on Internet Explorer 8 to
>   run their business.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx

If you have set your document mode to be anything higher than IE8, then it will eventually fallback to the emulated engine. Look at last paragraphs of page 14 of this Internet Explorer Standards Support Documentation Overview:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405771(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Another way to think of it is that IE8 document mode and EMIE are two different modes.  IE8 document mode is a rendering mode originally created during IE9.  It was meant to allow older websites to continue working,.  Unfortunately, other changes (such as security updates) got in the way.  Older website sort of worked, but not entirely.  During the IE11 project, part of the team provided EMIE as a way to provide a better simulation of IE8.  Older websites worked better, but it still wasn't 100% perfect.  Think of EMIE as a better IE8 document mode.  To learn more, see http://bit.ly/1cmanIK

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You know after January 12, 2006, most operating systems will end of support for IE9 and IE11.

Do you think you if IE9 and IE10 will be included in Enterprise Mode? I haven't seen any official statement.

Comment: I hope you are referring to the year 2016 and not 2006 :) End of support details are in here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie and moving forward, IE11 is the only version of IE to be supported starting at that point in time

Comment: @CharlesX: I think you mean January 12, 2016